# How can I print probability score for a named entity using stanford NER?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

inherently the classifier must be using a cut-off to classify an Entity in a certain class say person or organization.
how do I get that probability score?

for example can I get something like.
Hiranandani : location(0.8),builder(0.7),name(0.3)
where location,builder,name are different classes of named entity

Answer (score 2):

The Stanford NER uses a CRF to determine the NER type.  The NERDemo (see http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/ner-example/NERDemo.java) shows how you can print out the per token marginalized probabilities for each NER type (see call to classifier.printProbs).